# react-native flatList is grey out

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am using flatlist but the renderItem is gray-ed  out. while the item is rendering the component are gray out please help me with this.

[image: FlatList Screen]

this is my code

```
<FlatList
  data={this.state.serviceList}
  renderItem={({ item }) =>
    <>
      <Text style={styles.serviceDropText}>
        Title
      </Text>
      <View style={styles.dropdown}>
        <DropDownPicker
          items={this.state.products}
          defaultValue={this.state.country}
          containerStyle={{ height: 40 }}
          style={{ backgroundColor: '#fafafa' }}
          itemStyle={{
            justifyContent: 'flex-start'
          }}
          dropDownStyle={{ backgroundColor: '#fafafa' }}
          onChangeItem={item => this.setState({
            country: item.value
          })}
        />
      </View>
    </>
  }
  keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
/>
```

styles

```
serviceDropText: {
  fontSize: wp('4%'),
  fontWeight: 'bold',
  color:'black'
},
dropdown: {
  width: wp('60%')
},
```

Comment: I have taken your code and constructed the app at https://snack.expo.io/d5NmjM3dE. It is working fine. The text and dropdown are not grey-ed. Check if you are making any mistake or missed something.

Comment: ok @sriram, i will check. thanks

Comment: @sriram, i debugged and found that while using react-native-simple-radio-button the flat list is greyed out. any idea on this?

Comment: Can you please post the code you have used for react-native-simple-radio-button?

Answer (score 0):

You have to upload with full code at least about `styles`.
Did you make a mistake about styles something?

Comment: code is updated with styles, FYI: the styles are working fine without flatlist